# How to initialize CString& parameter in a function

Tags: c++, initialization, cstring

I have an existing function, and I'd like to add a parameter and set a default value for it so it won't affect other modules that use it.

```
BOOL myFunc(int A, CString& strTest);
```

Initializing it to NULL or 0 gives me an error message. How do I initialize strTest in my func declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try in this way

### A.h

```
class A{
    public:
      static CString defArg;
      bool myFunc(int A, CString& strTest=defArg);
 };
```

### A.cpp

```
CString A::defArg = "defArg";

bool myFunc(int A, CString& strTest){
 //what you need to do
}
```

Comment: instead of public, can I set static CString defArg; to private?

Comment: No prob man. It is up to you. as your requirement. if you no need to access this out side from class. make it private. :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably initialize it to an empty string:

```
CString dummy = "";

BOOL myFunc(int A, CString &strTest=dummy);
```

If you're allowing a default value, you probably want to make it a reference to a `const` string though:

```
BOOL myFunc(int A, CString const &strTest = dummy);
```

You might want to consider using overloading instead though -- leave the existing function exactly as it is (no extra parameter), and write a second function (that may forward to the first) that takes the extra parameter:

```
BOOL myFunc(int A);
BOOL myFUNC(int A, CString const &strTest);
```

Comment: when I assign a value to strTest inside myFunc, it says Error 1 error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const CString' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: @Owen: right -- if you make it const, you can't assign to it. If the user hasn't passed anything, where do you expect your assignment to go? I think you need to clarify what you want to accomplish -- trying to modify something that may not have been passed doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: inside myFunc() another function passes a string. I would like to assign that string to myFunc's strTest. Can I use const_cast ?

Comment: @Owen: Are you expecting what you assign to become visible to the caller of `myFunc`, or are you just using `strTest` as a local variable, so modifying it only changes what's visible locally?

Comment: I'm expecting your first point... "expecting what you assign to become visible to the caller of myFunc"

Comment: I just figured another way. Instead of passing by reference, I used CString pointer and later dereference it.